# jQuery-UI autocomplete is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I need using jQuery-ui "autocomplete" in an .net MVC program, but it is not working. Anybody can help me out will be great appreciated.

The view code is like below:

```
<head runat="server">
    <link href="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/ecmascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Product/GetProductName/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { categoryID: <%: Model.Select(o => o.Category.CategoryName).Distinct().Count() > 1 ? 0 : Model.FirstOrDefault().CategoryID %> },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#productNameSearch').autocomplete({
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(data),
                    focus: function(event, ui) {
                        $('#productNameSearch').val(ui.item.ProductName);
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        $('#productNameSearch').val(ui.item.ProductName);
                        $('#selectedValue').text("Selected value:" + ui.item.ProductID);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<% using (Html.BeginForm("ProductNameSearch", "Product", FormMethod.Post)) {%>
        <input type="text" id="productNameSearch" name="productNameSearch" style="width:300px" />&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
        <div id="selectedValue"></div>
<%}%>
```

The controller code is like below:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetProductName(int? categoryID)
{
    return Json(from p in pr.GetProductList() where p.CategoryID == 2 select new { ProductID = p.ProductID, ProductName = p.ProductName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Did you see any script error in firebug using firefox

Comment: There is no script error when check with firebug "error console".

Comment: What happends if you remove contentType as parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your returned json data looks something like this:

`[ { ProductID: 1, ProductName: "Red Hat" }, { ProductID: 2, ProductName: "Red Scarf" }]`

then the autocomplete has no idea what to display.

It needs a value and/or label field.

Try returning your data similar to this:

`[ { value: 1, label: "Red Hat" }, { value: 2, label: "Red Scarf" }]`

Maybe with this change (I'm not completely sure but you should get the idea):

`return Json(from p in pr.GetProductList() where p.CategoryID == 2 select new { value = p.ProductID, label = p.ProductName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

> > The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the label.

Comment: Thanks jk. :-) . The issue got solved after reading your post "If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the label." You may see my post answer.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code like below, it works perfect! Thanks "jk." !!!

The view code is like below:

```
<head runat="server">
    <link href="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/ecmascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Product/GetProductName/",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { categoryID: <%: Model.Select(o => o.Category.CategoryName).Distinct().Count() > 1 ? 0 : Model.FirstOrDefault().CategoryID %> },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    var dataFromServer = [];
                    for (i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
                        dataFromServer[i] = data[i].ProductName;
                    }
                };
                $('#productNameSearch').autocomplete({
                    source: dataFromServer
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("ProductNameSearch", "Product", FormMethod.Post)) {%>
        <input type="text" id="productNameSearch" name="productNameSearch" style="width:300px" />&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
<%}%>
```

The controller code is like below:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetProductName(int? categoryID)
{
    Product product = new Product { CategoryID = categoryID };
    return Json(from p in pr.SearchProductList(product) select new { ProductName = p.ProductName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```